# Creating a program to download Homestuck (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working for a program over the last few days which should download a range of pages from the webcomic [Homestuck](http://mspaintadventures.com). I've created a working version in python 3, but it is horribly inefficient. Can anyone see ways to improve and shorten this code?

```
import urllib.request
range1 = int(input("Enter the 1st page you want: "))
range2 = int(input("Enter the last page you want: ")) + 1
current = range1 + 1900
final = range2 + 1900
page = ''
nextPage = ''
while current != final:
    page = str(current)
    nextPage = str(current+1)
    while len(page) != 6:
        page = '0'+ page
    while len(nextPage) != 6:
        nextPage = '0'+ nextPage
    html = 'http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p='+page
    site = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
    s = site.read()
    s = s.decode("utf8")
    s = s.replace("<!-- end comic content -->", "<!-- begin comic content -->")
    s = s.replace("http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/", "")
    s = s.replace("?s=6&p=" + str(nextPage), str(int(nextPage))+".html")
    s = s.replace(page+"/"+page, page)
    a,b,c = s.split('<!-- begin comic content -->')
    b = "<title> Page " + page + "</title>" + b
    t = open(str(current)+".html", 'w+')
    t.write(b)
    t.close()
    page = str((int(page)-1900))
    while len(page) != 5:
        page = '0'+ page

    t = open(str(current)+".html", 'a')
    swfname=page+".swf"
    t.write("<object width='1000' height='1000'> <param name='movie' value='"+swfname+"'>")
    t.write("<embed src="+swfname+" width=650 height=450>")
    t.write("</embed>")
    t.write("</object>")
    t.close()
    try:
        img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+".gif"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+".gif")
    except:
        try:
            img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"_1.gif"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+"_1.gif")
            img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"_2.gif"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+"_2.gif")
        except:
            try:
                img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"/"+page+".swf"
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+".swf")
            except:
                print("Image "+img+" failed to download")
    print ("Page " + str(page) + " of " + str(final-1901) + " downloaded")
    current+=1
    print("DONE")
```

Comment: Maybe more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/? Also - is your indentation correct? At it stands, your code won't get past the first while loop.

Comment: The code works, so I probably formatted it wrong in stackoverflow. Also I didn't know about codereview, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't understand these lines :

```
t = open(str(current)+".html", 'w+')
t.write
```

2) You should avoid multiple writing in a file. It's better to use string formatting and then write once.

```
text='''<object width='1000' height='1000'> <param name='movie'  value='{0}'>
<embed src="{0}" width=650 height=450>
</embed>
</object>'''.format(swfname)
t.write(text)
t.close()
```

Comment: I fixed the first problem, but can you explain what you are doing in the second one?

Comment: You create a string with endline caracters (so you have to use `'''`) and you replace the {0}, {1},... with the first, second,... arguments of `format`. See [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more inforations